# Is having an IPv6 reverse lookup zone necessary for an Active Directory network?

Tags: active-directory, ipv6, best-practices

Is having an IPv6 reverse lookup zone necessary for an Active Directory network?

Normally I would just create it and move on, however, in this case the prefix is delegated and changes occasionally. So I have to create a new one every time the prefix changes.

Comment: Whether the answer is yes or no, you really should be using a ULA prefix, so that you have unchanging addresses to refer to everything on your network.

Comment: I'm open to using ULA, however, I haven't been able to gather enough information about how to set it up in combination with the public prefix. I asked http://serverfault.com/questions/804607/what-is-the-proper-way-to-configure-active-directory-and-domain-controllers-when , but didn't get any answers. Also, many of the articles I read (and one book), said that ULA should only be used in rare cases for isolated networks.

Comment: ULA is used for traffic that never enters the public Internet. You can use it for local traffic, and Global addresses for Internet traffic. IPv6 allows you to put many IPv6 addresses on an interface. To use ULA addressing, you must use the upper half of the `fc00::/7` range (`fd00::/8`), and the next 40 bits must be randomly assigned. The leaves you 16 bits for subnetting (65,536 subnets) before you need to get another 40 random bits.

Comment: "ULA should only be used in rare cases"? Er, you've been reading some very bad articles (and one book). _Everyone_ should be using ULA, from Fortune 500 companies down to the home network. Just set it up on the appropriate router (usually your edge router).

Comment: http://www.howfunky.com/2013/09/ipv6-unique-local-address-or-ula-what.html?m=1

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00HG2CQ34/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_WHvWybRS3Q6P1

Comment: That guy's article is way outdated, doesn't take into account how ISPs are actually (mis-)deploying IPv6, and focuses on the wrong things. ULA is not just about repeating the mistakes of NAT; it's also about working around the mistakes of ISPs. Dunno what's wrong with the book; I'm certainly not going to buy it just to critique it.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is having an IPv6 reverse lookup zone necessary for an Active Directory network?

A: No. Having an IPv4 reverse lookup zone isn't necessary either. AD doesn't use reverse lookup zones and therefore neither is necessary.